# MahApps.Metro: WindowCommands ItemsSource binding

Tags: wpf, mahapps.metro

I am trying to bind a collection of items to the `windowcommands` of `metrowindow`. Below is the xaml snippet.

```
<metro:MetroWindow.WindowCommands>
        <metro:WindowCommands ItemsSource="{Binding WindowCommands}">         
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Button Content="{Binding DisplayName}"
                            Command="{Binding Callback}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </metro:WindowCommands>
    </metro:MetroWindow.WindowCommands>
```

But it does not display the `DisplayName` property, but the type name of the bounded datatype. How can I achive the intended behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

Works if you add the template as a resource to the MetroWindow. For this to work you will need to create a WindowCommandViewModel that has Label and Callback properties.

```
<metro:MetroWindow.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModels:WindowCommandViewModel}">
        <Button Content="{Binding DisplayName}"
                Command="{Binding Callback}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</metro:MetroWindow.Resources>
```